# Parallel Function In C++

Tags: c++

I am creating a C++ application in which I am using a network camera. There are three functions in my program:

```
Initialize();
Start();
Release();
```

In the `Initialize()` function I initialize the camera and in `Start()` function I perform some action. In `Start()` function

```
void start()
{
  if(InternetCheckConnection(L"http://192.168.0.90",FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION,0))
  {
    // DO SMOME WORK
  }
  else
  {
    Initialize();
  }
}
```

I don't want the if-else logic. I want to initialize the camera for the first time using `Initialize()`, and then have an event which is continuously checking the `internetcheckconnection()` so that if `Start()` function is not called and camera will disconnected the parallel event automatically starts the camera.

Can some body please help me to create that type of event which continuously checks `internetCheckConnection()` in parallel with my program? I am looking for answers with example code.

Comment: Hey! Assuming you're using linux search for "pthread". if you're using windows search for "createthread"

Comment: @ultifinitus: Better still, search for [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) and do it portably. Assuming threads are appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that you want the thread to execute.

**Example:**

```
void Task(std::string m)
{
    std::cout << "Task message: " << m;
}
```

After that create the thread object that will invoke the function above:

```
std::thread thread1(Task, "Hi");
```

Add the header file `#include <thread>` to access the `std::thread` class

the thread will run the functions you passed as the constructor argument, with the parameter value you passed.

The Code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

//The function we want to make the thread run.
void CheckConnection(string msg)
{
    while(1) {
        if( InternetCheckConnection( L"http://192.168.0.90", FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0) ) {
        //Do some Work
        } else {
        //Start the camera
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    initialize();
    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    thread t1(CheckConnection, "Hello");

    // when process exits all threads terminate.
}
```

More information about [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) here

- On GCC compile with -std=c++11.
- On GCC versions below 4.7, use `-std=c++0x -pthread` (instead of
  `-std=c++0x`).
- This should work for any operating-system, granted your compiler
  supports this (C++11) feature.